# Tensorflow: problems about setting parameter"reuse" for "tf.get_variable"

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am reading a book about Tensorflow and an example is shown：

```
######################################################################

def inference (input_tensor,reuse=False):  
    with tf.variable_scope('layer1',reuse=reuse):
        weights=tf.get_variable("weights",[input_node,output_node1],

    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
        biases=tf.get_variable("biases",[output_node1],
                               initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        layer1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input_tensor,weights)+biases)

    with tf.variable_scope("layer2",reuse=reuse):
        weights=tf.get_variable("weights",[output_node1,output_node2],

    initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
        biases=tf.get_variable("biases",[output_node2],
                               initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        layer2=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(layer1,weights)+biases)
    return layer2

...
y=inference(x)
...

#############################################################################
```

When I try this, I receive an error:

```
Variable layer1/weights/Adam/ already exists, disallowed. 
Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? 
Originally defined at: ...
```

How to deal with this problem and...why is it occurring?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quJEr.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thZ9e.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the part that produces the error. This seems like you are defining your Adam optimizer multiple times in your code. Adam uses tensors for its intermediate results and therefore it is not possible to use multiple Adam optimizers for the same problem simultaneously without changing the default name. I commonly get this error, while messing around in jupyter notebooks, due to defining Adam multiple times. A quick fix for this is to restart your notebook and check that Adam is only defined once for a specific variable set.

You should define `test` and `t2` before you define your Adam Optimizer. It will still work as intended if you move line 69 and 70 after you first define your inference model.

Comment: When I restart my notebook(actually I am using spyder), it can work well indeed. After checked my code (a very simple example), I find that my Adam optimizer seems to be defined only once... I do not know what is going wrong...

Comment: If its a very simple example please post the full code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.I just uploaded the picture of my code. Are them available to you?

Comment: I made this change:I defined test and t2  as you told, but the same error occurs.

Comment: when I set : reuse = True in inference, the error is :Variable layer1/weights/Adam/ already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?  :################# and when I set : reuse = False , the error is :Variable layer1/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but it works for me. Seems to be your IDE who is messing with you as proven that it works from time to time by restarting your IDE.